# Inheritence in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, inheritance

For my current projection I'm making an application where I decided to use inheritance for my person classes. I have the parent class: contact and the children: klant (customer), leverancier (supplier) and chauffeur (driver). My database design looks like the following:

[image: Database design]

Note that I have a relation going from customer, supplier and driver to opdracht (task). I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this.

To do inheritance I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-type-inheritance/) (I can't choose an ADO.NET Entity Data model, I had to choose 'Linq to sql classes'), which works fine until step 7, where it tells me to delete the primary keys of my child tabels. I can't do this because I have relations from those those tables (like I said before).

I also can't do step 8, I can't find the window he is working in, all I can find is the following:

[image: settings in visual studio]

I have tried looking for more tutorials / help about this topic but I can't seem to be able to find anything about it. I assume I'm doing something wrong here, but I don't know what.

I hope somebody can help me. Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Framework and Linq To Sql are two different technologies. Entity Framework is the one that's recommended for new projects, especially if you want to use inheritance. EF supports multiple forms of inheritance, LinqToSql only Table per Class.

Since you are just starting I would advice you to switch to the Entity Framework. If you use the newest version (4.3 at this moment) you can choose between [Database First, Model First](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx) or [Code First](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-code-first-walkthrough.aspx).

[Here is the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723) to get you started on using the Entity Framework.